# How to compare 2 fields of same dataframe values and update result in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to compare 2 columns of same dataframe and update result in another column, if its matches update as `True` else `False`.

`df`:

```
Col1    Col2    Result
1234569 1234569 TRUE
256132  453543  FALSE
DSDFDSF DSDFDSF TRUE
TRYTR   FGFH    FALSE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This returns a boolean series:    `df.col1==df.col2`